# Unable to connect my bluetooth to pc or otherphone

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-pairing

I am unable to connect my bluetooth with my pc and with other phone but i can connect it to bluetooth headphone and speaker. I get pair option and device get paired (after confirmation ) but it do not get connected.
Phone Samsung J7 Nxt

I tried deleting caches and files of bluetooth in apps on my phome but it does not worked.

Comment: From your settings, go to the apps /app info section (depending on the Android version, it may vary), enable display of system apps, delete cache and try. If that doesn't help, delete data of Bluetooth app (you will lose all paired connections) and try.

Comment: still unable to connect and when i click on paired devive setting i only get internet access option earlier i used to get so many options

Comment: Reset Bluetooth in those devices that aren't getting connected, usually instructions or Google will tell you how to //If this doesn't help too, please [edit] to mention this as a troubleshooting step carried out, so that others don't suggest the same