# Disable lock screen with root or xposed in android 9

Tags: root-access, magisk, edxposed

I have an ASUS ZenFone Go (ZC500TG) running phh's Treble GSI Android 9 AOSP. I have both Magisk root and EdXposed (SandHook) Magisk Module installed.

My problem is that my school email requires me to have a lock screen set up to receive emails. This is really annoying. If I don't set up a lock screen, this message below pops up and there is no way to remove the notification. It seems that "Swipe to unlock" doesn't count as a lockscreen.

[image]

I also tried an Exposed Module, Lock screen Disabler. Unfortunately, it only supports Android 6 and below. I tried installing the Module on my phone and it doesn't work. The module hasn't been updated in a while from the creator.

I'm currently open to any solution that can disable the lockscreen and receive emails from my school, using a Magisk module, Xposed module or with root.

**Extra info:**

From my findings, it seems that Google Play Services has a service that detects whether there is a lockscreen present on the phone. The service is "Screen lock service". Unfortunately, I also tried disabling the service but it would reenable itself after a reboot. The service can be found at: Settings --> Security & location --> Device admin apps. It is a pain in the ass to disable the service everytime I did a reboot. (I do a lot of testing on the phone so it is normal for me to reboot frequently in a day).

I am also open to a solution where I can permanently disable this service and I don't need to set up a lockscreen. Root, Magisk module or Xposed module is okay.

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/229001/131553) //Why not use Gravitybox - enable "smart lock" and in "Trusted wifi" select your wifi. You won't need to unlock as long as you are connected to selected wifi while retaining lock screen

Comment: I'll try and see how it goes

Comment: Make sure GravityBox has location permission. Since 8.1,this is needed for Wifi detection

Comment: Alright, thanks